# prevent jQuery append from appending to iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I am trying to append to $('body'), but some sites use full html pages inside iframes, that means it -the page- has two -or more- body tags, i tried to use $('body').first(), but with no luck, any thoughts? same goes for html tag.

**EDIT 1**: as per request to show some code, i'll explain further, i am creating a chrome extension that appends a fixed div to the current page, everything works fine when there is only one html/body tag, other than that the div is appended to all of the html/body tags in the page, as someone said "give it an ID", i can't, this is not my page i have no real control over the server generated DOM, i only can inject into it, anyways here is the code that deals with appending the div.

```
formDiv = jQuery('<div/>', {
    id : 'fform',   
    class :'_fform',
    html : fhtml,
    style : 'left:' + document.body.scrollLeft + ';top:' + document.body.scrollTop
})

$('html').first().append(formDiv);
```

**EDIT 2**: i suspect it has something to do with "all_frames" in chrome extension manifest now.

Comment: $('body').first() should work, even if there's one body. Could you please show us some code?

Comment: `$('body').append('stuff here');` won't append anything to iframes, only to any `<body>` tag in the current document. Please clarify the problem and if possible construct a test case in jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the site is framed or not, and act accordingly?

```
formDiv = jQuery('<div/>', {
         id : 'fform',   
    'class' :'_fform',
       html : fhtml,
      style : 'left:' + document.body.scrollLeft + ';top:' + document.body.scrollTop
});
if (top === self) {
   $('html').append(formDiv);
} else {
   $(parent.document).append(formDiv);
}
```

On the other hand, you normally have to access the contextWindow to append to an iFrame, so just targeting regular tags should'nt be a problem.

Comment: You answered me in an indirect way, it was "all_frames" option in chrome manifest file, once i set it to it's default (false), now things work as they are supposed to.